# Install additional packages in sagemaker pipeline

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I want to install additional packages which will be used in processing step.

```
sklearn_processor = FrameworkProcessor(
    estimator_cls=SKLearn,
    framework_version='0.23-1',
    instance_type="ml.t3.medium",
    instance_count=1,
    base_job_name="sklearn-abalone-process",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    role=role
)

outputs = [
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source="/opt/ml/processing/validation"),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/test")
]

step_process = ProcessingStep(
    name="Preprocess_Data",
    processor = sklearn_processor.run(outputs=outputs,
        code="pre-process.py", dependencies=["/home/sagemaker-user/dependencies/requirements.txt"])
)
```

After running ProcessingStep, I am getting **ValueError: either step_args or processor need to be given, but not both.**

Sagemaker version is 2.197.0

I tried going through AWS Documentation but no luck

Comment: From the error message, it seems that you cannot provide both step_args and processor at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
step_args = sklearn_processor.run(outputs=outputs, code="pre-process.py", source_dir=BASE_DIR)

step_process = ProcessingStep(
    name="Preprocess_Data",
    step_args = step_args
)
```

Adding a note:

You do not need to specify `requirements.txt` as `dependencies` in the `sklearn_processor.run(..)`. The FrameworkProcessor will upload it for you. Just set the `source_dir` in `sklearn_processor.run(..)`. For more information check here:
https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_processing/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation.html#Running-processing-jobs-with-FrameworkProcessor-to-include-custom-dependencies

and

https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.FrameworkProcessor.run